# How to deploy kubernertes service (type LoadBalancer) on onprem VMs?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

How to deploy kubernertes service (type LoadBalancer) on onprem VMs ? When I using type=LoadBalcer it's shows external IP as "pending" but everything works fine with the same yaml if I deployed on GKS. My question is-:

Do we need a Load balancer if I use type=LoadBalcer on Onprem VMs?
Can I assign LoadBalncer IP manually in yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup metalLB.

MetalLB hooks into your Kubernetes cluster, and provides a network load-balancer implementation. In short, it allows you to create Kubernetes services of type `LoadBalancer` in clusters that don’t run on a cloud provider, and thus cannot simply hook into paid products to provide load-balancers.

To install run

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.9.3/manifests/namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.9.3/manifests/metallb.yaml
```

For more details Click [here](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/) to install

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to check the [Banzai Cloud Pipeline Kubernetes Engine (PKE)](https://banzaicloud.com/products/pke/) that is "a simple, secure and powerful CNCF-certified Kubernetes distribution" platform. It was designed to work on any cloud, VM or **on bare metal** nodes to provide a scalable and secure foundation for private clouds. PKE is cloud-aware and includes an ever-increasing number of cloud and platform integrations.

> When I using type=LoadBalcer it's shows external IP as "pending" but everything works fine with the same yaml if I deployed on GKS.

If you create a LoadBalancer service — for example try to expose your own TCP based service, or install an ingress controller — the cloud provider integration will take care of creating the needed cloud resources, and writing back the endpoint where your service will be available. If you don't have a cloud provider integration or a controller for this purpose, your Service resource will remain in Pending state.

In case of Kubernetes, LoadBalancer services are the easiest and most common way to expose a service (redundant or not) for the world outside of the cluster or the mesh — to other services, to internal users, or to the internet.

Load balancing as a concept can happen on different levels of the OSI network model, mainly on L4 (transport layer, for example TCP) and L7 (application layer, for example HTTP). In Kubernetes, Services are an abstraction for L4, while Ingresses are a generic solution for L7 routing.

> You need to setup metalLB.

MetalLB is one of the most popular on-prem replacements for LoadBalancer cloud integrations. The whole solution runs inside the Kubernetes cluster.

The main component is an in-cluster Kubernetes controller which watches LB service resources, and based on the configuration supplied in a ConfigMap, allocates and writes back IP addresses from a dedicated pool for new services. It maintains a leader node for each service, and depending on the working mode, advertises it via BGP or ARP (sending out unsolicited ARP packets in case of failovers).

MetalLB can operate in two ways: either all requests are forwarded to pods on the leader node, or distributed to all nodes with kubeproxy.

Layer 7 (usually HTTP/HTTPS) load balancer appliances like F5 BIG-IP, or HAProxy and Nginx based solutions may be integrated with an **applicable ingress-controller**. If you have such, you won't need a LoadBalancer implementation in most cases.

Hope that sheds some light on a "LoadBalancer on bare metal hosts" question.